# Emails from salesforce ending up as Spam

Tags: email

We are noticing for some days now that the emails sent by Salesforce are ending up in Spam folder of our customers.

I have read lot of blog posts / forums regarding this but could not reach a definitive conclusion.

Wanted to ask whether using a relay would solve that issue ? (Google Apps for Business, Mandrill by MailChimp etc)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have enabled "Email Security Compliance" as shown in image to identify the email authenticity:

[image]

Comment: already enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It could very well be your organization spam filter stamping a high value or tagging the message as spam based on the content or configuration change in your spam filters. 
If this is only recent behaviour then I would also suspect if the organization wide spam filter system itself has changed there by introducing new filter settings.
I am sure you have seen this: https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2015/02/5-mistakes-that-will-send-you-to-the-spam-folder.html

Comment: not worried about emails coming to us (our organisation users) but the emails going to Leads / Contacts (externals) sometimes are ending up as spam in GMail / Hotmail etc.